# In ActionScript, how to have sandboxType set to LOCAL_WITH_FILE?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am hoping to have a flash audio player being able to play (only) local files. The swf can be installed on the filesystem. My understanding is that if we have flash.system.Security.sandboxType equal to localWithFile, then it can access the file system, but now the network, which is exactly what I want.

So my question is what shall I do (or not do) to have this? If my file is referenced with a file://... link, and has not been explicitly trusted by the user in its flash settings, will flash.system.Security.sandboxType be automatically set to localWithFile?

Comment: You can choose network-only or local-only in the Publish Settings when you create the SWF, and if the SWF is played from the file system you'll get the sandbox you specified. (You can't change the sandbox at runtime obviously.) The user-changeable settings don't affect this at all, except that if the user specifies the file as trusted then you'll run in the Trusted sandbox (and be able to access both filesystem and network).

Comment: See e.g.: http://troyworks.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/flash_publish_settings_local_playback_security_access_local_files.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Security.LOCAL_WITH_FILE` reflects the way your SWF file was launched. It's not settable from the custom code. I.e. it means that your SWF file originated from the file system and the settings of the Flash player don't allow this file to connect to internet or communicate with environment. This, from your perspective, as a developer, is a given. You cannot influence this option. Any user can open Flash Player settings and give the file in question different permissions, thus making your assumption of sandbox type invalid.

I don't think there is, or may be a general case solution to your problem as other restrictions or permissions will take precedence. For example, if that same SWF will be served via HTTP, regardless of what you do, it will not have access to the local file system.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Whether a SWF can access local-only or network-only is a compile-time setting, if you're using Flash Pro you can choose the behavior in the "Publish Settings" dialog.

Comment: I know what's in the manual, and the answer remains incorrect. The question was if a SWF is opened locally and not trusted, what is necessary to make sure it gets the LOCAL_WITH_FILE sandbox? And the answer to that question is that it depends solely on the SWF publish settings. If that SWF was published with the "local files only" option then it will be able to access local files; if it wasn't then it won't. (If the user trusts the SWF then it will have local file access no matter what, but that wasn't part of the question.)

Comment: The question specifically states that the SWF is to be installed on the local filesystem and should read local files. That is the behavior described, and the *only* thing necessary to make that happen is publishing with the local files flag. What the user does is irrelevant, as user actions can only add additional permissions. As for your second point, I said *"if the user trusts the SWF"*. There is no such thing as trusting SWFs from the internet, if a SWF is trusted then it necessarily has been loaded from the local file system.

Comment: Are you suggesting the questioner needs the SWF to be restricted from reading internet files? I don't think he was asking that. (It could obviously be enforced inside the SWF.) The asker looks unlikely to clarify, but for future people who come to this for reference, the spirit of the question is clearly about whether anything needs to be done for a local, untrusted SWF to have access to local files. Your answer essentially implies that it's not possible - that the developer cannot influence whether LOCAL_WITH_FILE occurs. At best it's misleading, the answer should discuss the compile flag.